# PHPMailer cannot correctly merge contents

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Update:
enabled PHPMailer debug getting:

```
04-May-2023,18:06:13log_contents completed.
2023-05-04 09:06:13 Connection: opening to XXX.XXX:XXX, timeout=300, options=array ()
2023-05-04 09:06:13 Connection: opened
2023-05-04 09:06:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 SPSVRMAILDB02.seapower.mo Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 4 May 2023 18:07:07 +0900
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO XX.DOMAIN.XXX
2023-05-04 09:06:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SPSVRMAILDB02.seapower.mo Hello [192.168.XXX.XX]250-SIZE 37748736250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250 CHUNKING
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<XX@XXXXX.XXX>
2023-05-04 09:06:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<XX.XX@XX.XX>
2023-05-04 09:06:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.28 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_377eff022806XXXXXX3ea4f92bb02"
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_377eff022806cce60XXXXXXf92bb02
2023-05-04 09:06:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
is this still getting "chartset=us-ascii" correct?
but I already used `$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"`
```

new test: `$mail->MsgHTML($log_contents);` still not working...

---

---

I create some function read all log-file check for today update

then send the email to myself as re-check.

But I'm only getting the hard-code part but not the log-file content.

error when send to outlook:

[image]

but correctly working on web:

[image]

The `Class LogFileReader`

```
define("TIMESTAMP", date("d-M-Y,H:i:s"));
class LogFileReader {
  private $dir; // Declare a property to store the current directory
  private $today;  // Declare a property to store today's date
  private $log_contents;  // Declare a property to store the log contents
  private $timestamp; // Declare a property to store system datetime
    // Declare a constructor that takes the directory as an argument
  public function __construct($dir) {
    // Assign the directory to the property
    $this->dir = $dir;
    // Get today's date and time in Y-m-d H:i:s format
    $this->today = date("Y-m-d");
    // Prepare params, timestamp with initiates.
    $this->timestamp = TIMESTAMP;
    $this->log_contents = " <h2>$this->timestamp daily cron job running.</h2><br>\n";
  }

    // Declare a method that reads and processes the files
  public function readFiles() {
    // List all the .txt files in the directory
    $files = glob($this->dir . "/*.txt");
    // Loop through the files and display their content after today's date and time
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $this->log_contents .= "<h4>Filename: " . basename($file) . "</h4><br>\n";
      // Read the file content as an array of lines
      $file_content_lines = file($file);
      // Get the last 8 lines of the array
      $last_eight_lines = array_slice($file_content_lines, -8);
      // Filter out the lines that do not contain today's date and time or later
      foreach ($last_eight_lines as $line) {
        // If the line contains today's date and time or later, set the flag to true
        if (strpos($line, $this->today) !== false || strtotime($line) > strtotime($this->today)) {
          $flag = true;
        } // set flag for lines
        // If the flag is true, print the line
        if ($flag) {    $this->log_contents .= $line;    }
      }
      $this->log_contents .= " \n ---- ---- <hr>\n";
    }
  }

  // Declare a method that returns the log contents
  public function getLogContents() {
    return $this->log_contents;
  }
}
```

The usage:

```
// Create an instance of the FileReader class with the current directory
$log_files = new LogFileReader(getcwd());
// Call the readFiles method to process the files
$log_files->readFiles();
// Get and print the log contents
$log_contents = $log_files->getLogContents();
```

---

Where the error:
`PHPMailer` condition

```
if (!empty($log_contents)){ // after log_contents completed

  echo TIMESTAMP . "log_contents completed.<br/>\n"; // confirm log content completed.
  $email_content_head = "
  <h1>My Host XXXX daily crontab re-check</h1>
  <p>--- --- --- ---</p>
  "; // adding content head
  $emailContent = $email_content_head . $log_contents; // merge contents
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// which cannot correctly merge two contents
```

The
`PHPMailer html configs`

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Our Host XXX.XXX.XXX daily crontab re-check';
$mail->Body    = $emailContent;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

Did I miss sth? what am I doing wrong?

---

I've try adding

```
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";                                // set email encode to UTF-8
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';                              // if UTF-8 not working
```

but no luck of this, it still getting empty the `$log_contents`

And also try use `var_dump` for check the `$log_content` TYPE, but getting `string`

Is there anything else I can do

Comment: MS-Outlook is well known for the fact that it violates a number of standards both on protocol and visualization level. Often you only have the option to decide whether you want to support MS-Outlook or real email clients.

Comment: I don't think this is an outlook problem. It's most likely that your log reader isn't doing what you think it is, so don't assume anything, check that it is reading the files  correctly. For example it could be a difference in ownership or permissions on the log files between the two environments, and you have no error checking on the file reading code, so you can't tell that it's failing.

Comment: after the `if (!empty($log_contents)){ // after log_contents completed`, `PHPMailer` inside the `if-else` check for `$log_contents` then had a `try-catch wrapper`